# Read/write to stickynotes.snt?

Tags: c#, structured-storage, stickynote

I have done some searching on this topic and can't find any info from this year.
Has Microsoft released any API on how to read/write to the native Sticky Notes?
I have actually been able to read to it but I cannot write to it.
For reading I have used the python library here: [OleFileIO_PL](https://bitbucket.org/decalage/olefileio_pl/overview)
and anyone interested in a working version can see this pastie:[Read Stickynotes.py](http://pastie.org/8330205)
However now I would like to use .Net/C# to read AND write a new sticky note.

I have seen [this](http://www.niedermann.dk/2009/11/13/APIForStickyNotesInWindows7.aspx) but I am looking for something a little more clean. Any help is appreciated.

Also, has anyone used the MiTeC SSViewer? I was hesitant on using it because it was reported as a virus. [SSView](http://www.mitec.cz/ssv.html)